# Chaining callsArgWith on stub

Tags: sinon

I have gone through the documentation understand what exactly is stub.callsArgWith here:
    http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/

But I could not not understand what it makes sense when we chain it like below:

```
stub.callsArgWith(1, null, "ok")
    .callsArgWith(1, new Error("Error!"));
```

So, basically what it mean is param at index 1 is a callback function and it should be called with first param = null and 2nd param as "ok". But what I could not understand is in what situation we do chaining of callsArgWith and in what sequence are they get used.
Please help me in understanding what exactly is the meaning of above two lines how they will be executed, mean when will it take 'Ok' and when will it return an error.

Answer (score 0):

In older versions of `Sinon` (specifically versions 1.5 - 1.7), this was how you described behaviour for consecutive calls.

Otherwise, the second `callsArgWith` call replaces the behaviour of the first `callsArgWith`.

---

So in the your example (and assuming the version of `Sinon` is v1.5 - 1.7):

```
stub.callsArgWith(1, null, "ok")
    .callsArgWith(1, new Error("Error!"));
```

When the stubbed function is called for the first time,
it will call the 2nd parameter of the stubbed function with the parameters `null` and `"ok"`.

The second time the stubbed function is called, it will call the 2nd parameter of the stubbed function with an `Error` object.

---

So in the your example (and assuming the version of `Sinon` is **NOT** v1.5 - 1.7):

```
stub.callsArgWith(1, null, "ok")
    .callsArgWith(1, new Error("Error!"));
```

Every time the stubbed function is called it will call the 2nd parameter of the stubbed function with an `Error` object.

---

Documentation Link: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/#defining-stub-behavior-on-consecutive-calls

Comment: Sorry, I'm reading the question on this topic, and I cannot grasp it. "It will call the 2nd parameter of the stubbed function with the parameters null and 'ok'" - where is the stubbed function? How can one call "a parameter"?